# I am unable to connect to Mongodb using mongosqld on windows

Tags: mongodb, powerbi

I am trying to create an on prem BI connector for my Atlas MongoDB Database.
I have been able to install the connector but when i run

```
mongosqld --mongo-uri "mongodb://<URI-REPLICA-NODE-1:PORT>,<URI-REPLICA-NODE-2:PORT>,<URI-REPLICA-NODE-3:PORT>/?replicaSet=<URI-REPLICA-SET>&retryWrites=true&w=majority" --auth -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD> --addr 127.0.0.1:3309 --mongo-ssl
```

But i am getting this error

unable to load MongoDB information: failed to create admin session for loading server cluster information: unable to execute command: server selection error: context deadline exceeded...

i have not yet found a viable solution for this. please help or point me in the right direction.

i am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/qimi-techblog/connecting-mongodb-hosted-in-mongo-atlas-with-powerbi-including-m0-clusters-ae02fbef0c7d#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImYxMzM4Y2EyNjgzNTg2M2Y2NzE0MDhmNDE3MzhhN2I0OWU3NDBmYzAiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.KWiQ4YGY-2FpBTY3f1wYVO4wfVYDn8lLmCJsSYVgULIM5eA6MngIKKKPZ-grjRlz05ihQx4U0xYhngQHx7jfxQfpPEmeAG39RMqonwutObV83f6Em1CIw-AgPT5iUyvz9wBz9_CuD-e7xCZ-1BfOHdBvvU4KWGRBnhBdfUjiXHoX2-756aW4aTw0005JH09MLUClLeuGD-LQeN_OB8_JzJp3Oso_XIxPqSJRebitoTKs-IiRLMBbe6F9LBX9JPL0h8BrxRsJf8hy43Z4xDWjzGGJwAf6MXcu6Z_Zu5N7Tsay7nMnpUYsC_b8YtdQCMtgGyhZwGDIcrY-QjKa7Y7g9w)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve it. Apparently I had not whitelisted the IP address of the system where I was running mongosqld on.

As soon as I whitelisted it on my database it worked.